# Algorithm for assigning teachers and students to classes based off capability and preference

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem where I have n students and m teachers and I want to automatically make class lists based on this data. The teachers can be capable to teach up to four subjects, but can only end up teaching one (I.e. a teacher could list they’re capable to teach subjects one and two, but they end up being assigned to teach subject one.) Each of the students has a first and second preference for the subject they want to take, so one student could want to take subject four, but their second choice is subject three. Each subject can have multiple classes, and each class should have one teacher (so subject one could have two classes, each taught by its own teacher that is capable to teach that class)

My goal is to make an algorithm that automatically makes class lists that contain the number of classes per subject, along with the teacher that teaches each class and also to assign the kids to these classes based on their preferences.

The class sizes should generally be the same, at least between subjects taught.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I’ve only been able to figure out assigning volunteers that can only teach one class to that class, everything else I’m not sure how to do.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367)

Comment: What do you want to maximize? Number of classes? Number of satisfied students? What are the constraints? Can students take two classes? What do you mean by "class sizes should generally be the same"?